# How can I search array of names in an element of an array

Tags: arrays, c

I have this task/function to determine if student's name/complete name already exist in the record.
No student's name should be the same in every input/entry. also no duplicate  of entry in record.

The Error of my code:

Is that when I input 5 student names (e.g : A,B,C,D,E) then and search for D the return value will be not found. So I wonder what would be the correct logic for it to search every element if it exist? And when I tried A it says "Already Exist".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){


    char studentNames[50][50],names[50][50];
    int i,studentcount;


    printf("\nEnter number of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&studentcount);
    for(int i=0; i<studentcount; i++){
        printf("\n[Student %d of %d]\n",i+1,studentcount);
        printf("Enter name of student %d: \n",i+1);
        scanf("%s", studentNames[i]);
    }//this is the student record initialize.


    /*assumed this is a function where it holds the data name to be searched
    
    e.g 

     names[i]= "spiderman" then in studentNames[i]="venom",studentNames[i]="harley",studentNames[i]="octopops",
    
        if i loop will it function like this? 
         the names[i]=spiderman  compare to studentnames[i]=venom then if not equal iterate to harley and so on. 
         That's what I really want to do with my searching but I really dont know how to do it because of my poor logic thinking.  
    
    
    */
    for(int i=0; i<studentcount; i++){
       printf("\nEnter Student's Name to be search: ");
         scanf("%s",names[i]);
            
                   if (strcmp(studentNames[i],names[i]) == 0)
                                {
                                printf("Already exist.\n");
                                return 0;
                                }
                                printf("Not found\n");
                                return 1;

    }
```

}

Comment: In order to find if an element exists in an array you need to check *all* elements until you find the element (or reach the end of the array). Your code only compares a single element from both arrays

Comment: @UnholySheep is that an algorithm like linear search? Sorry I'm really a newbie

Comment: Please show [mcve]. It is not clear how your variables are defined.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I defined it 2d arrays too like the names array

Comment: I do not see any reason for `names` to be an array(of strings) - it is just a query and should be a single temporary string.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was like thinking defining names to be an array so that it would compare names[] to studentname[0] and iterate if not == then proceed to next array. I'm really sorry I have bad logic.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni ok sir I'll fix and complete my question and also the code.

Comment: The logic is simple: 1) Read a query (outside the loop). 2) Iterate the existing names comparing each to the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223104/discussion-between-drew-d-and-eugene-sh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
char CompareStudent() {
  printf("\nEnter Student's Name to be search: ");
  char searchedname[100];
  scanf("%99s", searchedname);   // %99s instead of %s prevents buffer overflow
                                 // (not very important at your level)

  for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
    if (strcmp(studentNames[i], searchedname) == 0) {
      printf("Already exists.\n");
      return 0;
    }
  }

  printf("Not found\n");
  return 1;
}
```

This is your original bogous code with comments:

```
char CompareStudent() {
  printf("\nEnter Student's Name to be search: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
    scanf("%s", names[i]);                          // 1

    if (strcmp(studentNames[i], names[i]) == 0)
    {
      printf("Already exist.\n");
      return 0;
    }
    printf("Not found\n");                          // 2
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Problems:

1. You need to ask to input the student to search only once, not each time in the loop
2. This part must be outside the loop. In your code, we return inconditionally 1 if the student is not in the first element of the array.

Comment: An explanation of what was wrong in the original code and what this changes would make this answer much more useful to the person asking

Comment: @ChatterOne explanation has been added in the meantime

Comment: @Jabberwocky I see thank you sir for your wonderful answer. I see where my error is. I really thought that if I put it inside the loop it will iterate each time thats why I really need to understand deeply how array and function works.

Comment: @DrewD instructions are executed sequencially.

Comment: @Jabberwocky sir are u still there? I have new questions regarding to this topic too maybe a tweak. Is it possible to use the compareStudent function to check the whole array or before initializing students name if it existed. then if didnt I insert them to the studentsName array?

Comment: @DrewD I didn't understand the question in your last comment, but anyway, you should post another question

Comment: @Jabberwocky https://stackoverflow.com/q/64385216/7366544 can u check this problem too sir im having trouble for fixing my own code hahaha